# c# wpf access value in column of listview

Tags: c#, wpf, xml

I have a ListView bound to XML. The XAML looks like this:

```
<ListView Name="patientsListView" ItemsSource="{Binding}" SelectionChanged="patientsListView_SelectionChanged">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView x:Name="patientGrid">
            <GridViewColumn Header="PatientName" Width="Auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding XPath=PatientName}" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="PatientAccountNumber" Width="Auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding XPath=PatientAccountNumber}" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="DateOfBirth" Width="Auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding XPath=DateOfBirth}" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

When a row is clicked, I want to do something:

```
private void patientsListView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
        //do stuff
        MessageBox.Show();
        }
```

If I click on a row, how do I access a value in a column individually? When debugging, I can see in Locals in the listview SelectedItems that my data is in the the InnerText in the Results View for whatever index, but I don't know how to get the value in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var patient = ((ListViewItem) sender).Content as Patient; //or whatever object type
```

From there you can get `patient.PatientName`, etc

[EDIT] Now that I look at it, I'm not 100% sure this will work within a selectionchanged event.  But it will work on a row click event.

However, if you're just trying to update another part of the UI, you can do something like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedItem.PatientName,ElementName='patientGrid'}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks! Not exactly the answer I was looking for, but your final comment sparked a thought updating my UI...and I had to add IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" to my ListView.

Comment: @CraigV  I'm glad I was able to help a bit :)

Answer (score 1):

In Debug mode find out the type of listview.SelectedItems, than convert it in that type

```
var item = (ItemType)listview.SelectedItems
```

than you can get value you want like this

```
item.PatientName
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the `sender` from `object` to `dynamic` and continue to use `dynamic` for other columns.